# How to set custom attribute that is only valid on return int value function

Tags: c#, attributes

I know AttributeUsage class. This class can set only property or method or class ...etc
I need custom attribute that is only acitve on method and method must return int value. 
If any function return string value, this attribute will don't work. Only work on int value.

Is there any like this attribute?

How can i create?

Is it possible?

Comment: Are you wanting this attribute to produce a compile time error?  Or a run time error?

Comment: Isn't there something that is consuming this attribute that can make that distinction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can only be determined at run time unfortunately.  If you want to receive notification that some usage of this attribute is violating this constraint, you may want to make use of a post build action.